# How to set Custom size to Present Modally ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I have `ViewController` and when user clicks at a bottom of it then other `ViewController` pops-up using segue `Present Modally`. 
Is it possible to give custom size to them ? I tried giving Content Size by `Use Preferred Explicit Size` option but it didn't help. I want that VC to pop up and take 70% of the current VC from up.

Comment: Are you trying on iPhone or iPad?

Comment: iPhone only as of now.

Comment: You can check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811199/ios-8-change-the-size-of-presented-modal-view-controller

Comment: Present Modally will always cover whole screen. If you want to utilize its 70% then you should go with ContainerView

Comment: ContainerView will take a view of your NextView controller view

Comment: I tried using ContainerView but I have many VC which will come as pop over when an option is selected. So having ContainerView was creating lot of confusion.

Comment: As per my understanding ContainerView is best solution for such functionality.

Comment: @DheerajD we cannot embed multiple VCs to `ContainerView` right ?

Comment: Not using storybboard but you can change its view at run time

Comment: @DheerajD Can you please share me link for tutorial or something regarding that ? I'm not much familiar with `ContainerView` much.

Comment: Sure... just posting a sample code in answer have a look and let know if got any issue

Comment: Use AutoLayout to a subview of the controller's view (make the super view's background color to .clear).

Comment: Do you want to display previous view's 30 % portion after presenting viewcontroller ?

Comment: @Lion Yes that is at below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using `UIContainerView` instead of "Present Modally" segue.

This is how I did it in case anyone else is struggling with same issue.

DO NOT SET ANY SEGUE/EMBED TO VC B/W `UIContainerView`. Add STORYBOARD ID.

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
weak var currentViewController: UIViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.currentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContainerVC")
    self.currentViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addChildViewController(self.currentViewController!)
    self.addSubview(subView: self.currentViewController!.view, toView: self.containerView)

    super.viewDidLoad()

}
//MARK:- CONTAINER VIEW

func addSubview(subView:UIView, toView parentView:UIView) {
    parentView.addSubview(subView)

    var viewBindingsDict = [String: AnyObject]()
    viewBindingsDict["subView"] = subView
    parentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[subView]|",
                                                                             options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict))
    parentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[subView]|",
                                                                             options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict))
}

func cycleFromViewController(oldViewController: UIViewController, toViewController newViewController: UIViewController) {
    oldViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    self.addChildViewController(newViewController)
    self.addSubview(subView: newViewController.view, toView:self.containerView!)
    newViewController.view.alpha = 0
    newViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        newViewController.view.alpha = 1
        oldViewController.view.alpha = 0
    },
                               completion: { finished in
                                oldViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
                                oldViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
                                newViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    })
}
```

**THEN WHENEVER YOU WANT TO CHANGE VIEW ACCORDING TO ACTION**

```
    let newViewController : DestinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationVC") as! DestinationVC
    newViewController.data = dataToBeSentViaSegue // Passing DATA
    newViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.cycleFromViewController(oldViewController: self.currentViewController!, toViewController: newViewController)
    self.currentViewController = newViewController
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into this and let me know if you want any clarification.

```
__weak IBOutlet UIView *conViewers;

- (void)callingOfCustomView:(UIViewController *)showPushedVC
{

    [showPushedVC.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
    showPushedVC.view.frame = conViewers.bounds;
    //**>> Add child view into container view
    [conViewers addSubview: showPushedVC.view];
    [self addChildViewController: showPushedVC];
    [showPushedVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

    ViewersVC *objViewers = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewersVC"];

    [self callingOfCustomView:objViewers];
```

Will update this in swift.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a view of 70 % of size on your second `VC` (I mean which you are presenting), and set background color of that `VC's view` as `clear color` so for that remaining 30 % will display previous VC.

For example your VC's height is 100 px then add another `view` with height of `70 pixel` and set `clear background color` to `self.view` I mean main view of VC!

Now set `modalPresentationStyle` to your VC before presenting it like,

```
  yourVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

     [self presentViewController:yourVC animated:YES completion:^{


    }];
```

If you are giving support lesser than `ios 8` then you need to set `setModalPresentationStyle` to `NavigationController(If you are using else parent view controller - which are presenting view controller)` like,

```
     [self.navigationController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];

     [self presentViewController:yourVC animated:YES completion:^{


    }];
```

**Swift :**

```
    yourVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext

    self.presentViewController(yourVC, animated: true) {

    }
```

or

```
    self.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext

    self.presentViewController(yourVC, animated: true) {

    }
```

Comment: But I need actions which will be performed in the buttons which will be on below 30% of the view. And according to selection of button, my above content changes.

Comment: Also got this error with this `reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller`

Comment: If you want to handle actions from that portion then you should go with `ContainerView` or you can add same kind of UI in current view so that anyone can feel that it's of previous one!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for help