# Can't Present View Controller Modally, with specific size

Tags: ios, swift3, presentviewcontroller

I have a View Controller in which it presents another view controller, modally (bottom-top animation).

I'm trying to present the View Controller, with a specific size, I want it to be presented modally , but in this case to be 80% of it's native size.

```
let newVC = tabBarController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newPostVC") as? NewPostVC
newVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBarController.view.frame.width, height: tabBarController.view.frame.height * 0.8)

tabBarController.present(newVC, animated: true)
```

But the view controller gets presented in its full size (screen size).
I think that I've to twerk the view controller's size, but I might be wrong.

My view controller in the storyboard has it's Transitional Style set to: Cover Vertical and the Presentation is set to: Full Screen.

Could this be the issue?

Can you give me a hint?

Thanks :)

Comment: I've tried using `newVC.view.layer.masksToBounds = true` and it didn't help

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811199/ios-8-change-the-size-of-presented-modal-view-controller

Comment: Hmm.. seems that's for me :D
I'll take a look. thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios 8 change the size of presented/modal view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811199/ios-8-change-the-size-of-presented-modal-view-controller)

Comment: the link you've provided is a bit outdated, it's from 2014 for iOS 8, and the explanation there is slightly confusing though

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this.

Create a `ContainerVC` programmatically add `newVC` as a subView . In the ContainerVC `viewDidLoad()`

1. set constraints on `newVC` to be `80%` of the container size. You can use some framework like `Anchorage` to easily set this constraints.
2. set your `backgroundColor = .clear`
3. Set the presentation style to `.overCurrentContext` like this `modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext`

While presenting it you can something like this

```
//create view controller
    let VC = ContainerVC()
//present modal
    self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I figure it out. I was using an animation for dismissing view controller inside a container. I've implemented a animation for presenting the view controller, inside the container with specific / desired properties and it worked.